# How to force HTTP for some pages in HTTPS forced website with htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, https

A part of my htaccess that redirects HTTP traffic to HTTPS looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I need allow some pages (lets say /page1, /page2) be HTTP only. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically such URIs containing `page1` or `page2` don't have to be rewritten:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page[0-9]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I simply added another condition check for that to exclude such URIs.